# Cmake with fruit tests

Tags: testing, cmake, fortran

I have a project that uses fruit for testing (fortran code).
This is my code.

**calculator.f90**

```
module calculator
   implicit none
   contains
   subroutine add (a, b, output)
       integer, intent(in) :: a, b
       integer, intent(out):: output
       output = a+b
   end subroutine add
end module calculator
```

And my test **calculator_test.f90**

```
module calculator_test
   use fruit
   contains
   subroutine test_5_2_2
      use calculator, only: add
      integer :: result
      call add(2,2,result)
      call assertEquals(4,result)
   end subroutine test_5_2_2

   subroutine test_5_2_3
      use calculator, only: add
      integer :: result
      call add(2,3,result)
      call assertEquals(5,result)
   end subroutine test_5_2_3
end module
```

Now I'd like to use Cmake to build and run my tests (triggered by jenkins), so my question is: Do I need to change the tests or is it possible to just run the test I've written through cmake, and if so how?
I've searched a lot online but all testing with cmake seems to be done with c++ and then by using executeable testfiles files.

Thanks!
-Minde

Comment: I have answered below assuming you already know CMake.  If not, let me know and I can add some details to get you started.  If the response is not clear enough, please add some detail to your question so that is more clear what you need to do in CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the tests you have written as is, you just need to tell CMake how to run them.  This is what the `COMMAND` argument to `ADD_TEST` is for.

```
ENABLE_TESTING()
ADD_TEST(NAME "YourTest" 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TEST_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND ${TEST_DIRECTORY}/test_dim)
```

Usually, you see some example like the one above, where the command is an executable (as you have seen in c++ examples).  But it doesn't have to be.  For example, I am running python tests through CMake, and I add the test like so:

```
ADD_TEST(NAME PythonTests 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TEST_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} setup.py test
```

So, to run your Fruit tests, you would call the command that creates the Fruit test runner for you (I believe it is a `rake` command... I will assume this is true below, but you should substitute for whatever you actually call on the command line to run your tests):

```
ADD_TEST(NAME FruitTests 
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TEST_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND rake test) # Or whatever the command is.
```

When you run `make test` on the command line, it should tell you if "FruitTests" failed or succeeded.

**A word of caution**  CMake determines the success or failure of the test by the exit code of the program.  By default Fortran programs do not have a exit code (or if they do, it is always 0).  When I use Fruit and CMake to do my Fortran tests, I write the test runner myself and use the `call exit(exit_code)` builtin subroutine to make sure an exit code is returned to CMake.  I am not sure if Fruit's automatic test runner creator does this; you will have to verify this yourself.

Comment: I was of the impression that i had to use an executeable in the "add_test" command so this was spot on. Thank you!